# "A nested structure of tf.Tensor objects" for Iterator.get_next() result type

Tags: python, tensorflow

When I write Tensorflow code, I try to keep in mind the type of different things, e.g. tuple of two Tensors, or list of Tensors. This is important because when the types/shapes don't match, Tensorflow emits an error.

The text of the title of this question shows up a lot in the documentation especially when describing the result of some function, e.g. for [`Iterator.get_next()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Iterator#get_next), but I find it too vague. It doesn't tell me exactly what to expect, a list of tuples? a tuple of tuples? What exactly is this 'nested structure'? Right now, the only way I can track this is to print the result after Session.run(). Is there a cleaner and more definitive way?

Also, it seems that the value of `Iterator.get_next()` is always a list of one element; I haven't been able to make it return a non-list, an empty list or a list with multiple elements. When does `Iterator.get_next()` return something that's not a list of one element? If never, then the wrapping of the content in a list seems superfluous -- why was `Iterator.get_next()` designed this way?

This is example code showing I mean:

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(np.array(range(0, 8)).reshape(4,2))
it = ds.make_one_shot_iterator()

with tf.Session() as sess:
    for i in range(0, 4):
        x = sess.run([it.get_next()])
        print(x)
```

Output:

```
[array([0, 1])]
[array([2, 3])]
[array([4, 5])]
[array([6, 7])]
```

Why not just the following?

```
array([0, 1])
array([2, 3])
array([4, 5])
array([6, 7])
```

Comment: May be because tuples in Tensorflow are returned generally as a list of tensors, the iterator supports the nested structure? A generic use case is 
tf.data.Dataset.from_tesnor_slices((data, labels))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your specific issue of "Output" vs. "Why not just the following?" results from passing in a list to `sess.run`.  If you instead use `sess.run(it.get_next())` you will get the desired behavior.

Note that TensorFlow allows you to pass in several different structures (e.g., lists, dictionaries, namedtuples, etc.), including nested structures (see [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/framework/nest)).  It will return the data following the same structure you used to pass it in.

For example, with a dictionary:

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(np.array(range(0, 8)).reshape(4,2))
it = ds.make_one_shot_iterator()

with tf.Session() as sess:
    for i in range(0, 4):
        x = sess.run({'x': it.get_next()}])
        print(x)
```

Output:

```
{'x': array([0, 1])}
{'x': array([2, 3])}
{'x': array([4, 5])}
{'x': array([6, 7])}
```